# kafka streams logging disable INFO

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Is there any way to disable Kafka streams processing summary info? because it will take alot of disk space

e.g  INFO 21284 --- [-StreamThread-6] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [test-20-37836474-d182-4066-a5f5-25b211e2fbdb-StreamThread-1] Processed 0 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 0 total tasks since the last update

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure it with [StreamsConfig](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.html) to disable processing summary (current version [3.2.X](https://kafka.apache.org/32) KStream API) instead you can control kafka log appender by the desired level and class with your logging framework, here is alternate form for configuring [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) as one practice,

- **log4j2.properties**

```
...
logger.org.apache.kafka.streams.name=org.apache.kafka.streams
logger.org.apache.kafka.streams.level=ERROR
...
```

- **log4j2.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka.streams" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
    ...

    </Loggers>
    <Appenders>
    ...
    </Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

Put either of config file with other appenders and formatter you may have to the root directory of the project.